# Viewing file in emacs that exceeds maximum buffer size

Tags: emacs, size, buffer, large-files, max

Is it possible to view part of the file at a time? BTW I am on 64-bit Ubuntu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [comp.emacs](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.emacs/2006-04/msg00009.html):

> You can load only part of a file with:
>   insert-file-contents-literally and:
>   insert-file-contents
>
> and you can save part of a buffer
>   with: append-to-file and: write-region
>
> You can pass an integer seek position
>   to write-region for the append
>   parameter to update a record in the
>   middle of the file.

You may be able to install a 64-bit Emacs package (or build one yourself) to up the buffer size limit to about a million terrabytes.

Comment: I have googled and found a insert-file command (C-x i), but no insert-file-contents command.

Comment: @Bluebomber357: Any Emacs command can be run with `M-x <command>`. So `M-x insert-file-contents` will do it.

Comment: Is there a man page or something for insert-file-contents? Now I am not sure what the parameters are.

Comment: @Bluebomber357: Use the Emacs built-in help: `M-x describe-function` <enter> `insert-file-contents`

Comment: @Bluebomber357 - shortcut for M-x describe-function is **C-h f** {function name} (it's useful to know that tab completion works on function names :) )

Answer (score 5):

Not really, no.  See [VLF](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/VLF) and [EmacsFileSizeLimit](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsFileSizeLimit) for discussion.

Not to be a wise-guy, but perhaps you should think about if looking at a giant file in an editor is really what you want to do.  Can you get whatever you want done using grep (perhaps with additional context lines) or sed if it's a one time thing, or a simple script if you are going to be do it over and over?

Comment: +1 For `sed`, I'll also suggest `awk` incase @Bluebomber357 hasn't used it before.